# What filters are available for Prompto to use?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I can't seem to find a list online, so I was curious. I noticed that I have a few filters that aren't mentioned in [this guide](https://samurai-gamers.com/final-fantasy-15-ffxv/photography-skill-guide-final-fantasy-15-ffxv/), like Vintage, Time, and Pop.

Are there any others? Where do I get them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prompto has 10 Photo Skills, 5 of which are filters. The Official Guide does not list any additional filters, however a few exist. I haven't personally been able to obtain more than the three you've already acquired.

[image]

Filters:

1. Roadtrip
2. Memory
3. Dawn
4. Bloom
5. Journey

Additional filters:

- *Pop*

> Gained by having the personal discussion with Prompto on the rooftop
>  of the hotel in *Longwyth*

- *Time*

> Gained during the quest "*A Place Called Home*."

- *Vintage*

> Gained by camping at the site near *Alstor Slough* and following
>  Prompto when he asks.

---

These can be adjusted in the Archives Menu under Filters. The player can set them to be used:

- Random
- Often
- Sometimes
- Never

.

Comment: I haven't seen anyone come forward with a more complete list, so unless one shows up in the future, I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Shawn Gordon's answer has all the details you need but if I may add to this,
If you go in to Ascension in the main menu and buy the link skill "Snapshot", you can level Prompto's photography skill up incredibly fast. I got to level 10 before chapter 4 just playing around with it. 
Personally speaking, I prefer the photos without filters as I think colours can look a bit washed out but his level 10 skill Self Timer is great for getting photos of Promto that aren't selfies!

Have fun! :)

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question about what filters are available.